# How to add an Iterop in Visual Studio 2010 like you can in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Does anyone know how to add a reference to "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mqoa30.tlb" in Visual Studio 2010 like you can in Visual Studio 2008?

If I go to Add Reference, and browse to this file: "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mqoa30.tlb" these are the different results:

**Visual Studio 2008**

[image: Added Just fine]
Added Just fine

[image: Creates Interop]

And creates the Interop stuff

**Visual Studio 2010**

[image: Does not add]

*The error message in clear text for SEO:*

```
Could not add a reference to C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mqoa30.tlb
Could not load file or assembly 'mqoa30.tlb' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
This file may not be a managed assembly.
```

Cannot add from the Add Reference Dialog and "Microsoft Messaging Queue 3.0 Type Library" is not listed already in the COM Type Libraries.

(Note: I have MSMQ installed and working fine (via NServiceBus).  I am running Windows 7.)

---

If you know how to add the reference can you please tell me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what it looks like on my version of VS2010, works fine.  No clue what your screenshot might represent, some sort of add-on I guess.

[image]

Comment: Interesting... That addon is Microsoft's "Productivity Power Tools" (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/).  I assumed since they were from Microsoft, they would be fairly safe to install.  Guess I was wrong.  I disabled Microsoft's "Productivity Power Tools" and I was able to add the reference just fine.   Thanks for the help!