# Different version for COM Interop DLL

Tags: vb6, msmq

I'm working with an old project written in both C# and VB.NET and VB6. I'm using VS 2012. I downloaded the build files directly from a build server so I could work locally. There are almost 90 sub projects and each has a copy of Interop.MSMQ.dll. Not only that but the sizes differ. I'm not sure this is a problem or simply how COM component are used. Or should be resolved; but how, since they differ.

Comment: The MSMQ COM interop dll is [generated by importing c:\windows\system32\mqoa30.tlb](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8258952/43846) so could vary depending on the OS version and architecture when it was imported. Whether this is a problem depends on whether it works as is, as changing them would be a risk: however if you wanted to, you could reference one version from all the projects.

Comment: You can use the ["primary interop assembly"](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baxfadst(v=vs.110).aspx) to avoid this happening. The idea is that the author of the COM component (in this case Microsoft) produces one definitive interop DLL for you to use. I don't know whether there is one for msmq - I would hope so. Search for it.